# Prevent Django forms highlighting correct fields

Tags: django, forms

After submitting a form that contains errors, the incorrect fields get marked as such. Correctly submitted fields, however, also get marked.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I'd prefer it if Django were to only render the incorrect fields differently, and render the correctly submitted fields as normal.

I checked the API offered by the `Form` object, but there does not seem to be a property that lists these correctly submitted fields.

Comment: How are you rendering the form in your template? Please, provide some code

Comment: I should've posted code. I guess the lesson here is never to post SO questions when you're in a hurry, as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django by default only marks the invalid fields, not the valid ones.
Be sure you are passing the POST data to the form in the view when POST.
(incomplete example below)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # your code then redirect
else:  #GET
    form = YourForm()
```

You can take a look to [this Django example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view) for a full example.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the correct way. I was using this, but wrapping it with django-bootstrap3, which appears to automatically set a class for success (`success_css_class`). Turns out it's a [well-documented setting](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html).